# Getting the list of every web address being accessed?

Tags: c#, .net, web

I've been trying very hard to write a code in C# that lets me know what web address is accessed from my computer no matter which browser I am using or which software is accessing that web address.

This is very important because there might be softwares on my computers opening up web pages in the background that I am not aware of.

I need the code to have a list of the web addresses, even if the recording begins when ever you run the program its fine...

Comment: Use a HTTP proxy like fiddler and you will save a lot of time and hassle writing your own.

Comment: Is this because you actually need the tool or you want to learn how to do it? Because if it's the latter, that's a really bad plan. If I want to drive to Brooklyn, I don't try to build my own bridge.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz And if you want to become a bridge builder? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you might want is a proxy server.

Check out [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Use Fiddler, you can get it here...

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: +1 for suggesting software that already does the job OP described perfectly well